# Python - Chi-Squared test for distribution where a value has 100% probability

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, chi-squared

I am kind of rusty on statistics, but I currently need to use the chi-squared test to verify if two probability distributions are statistically similar.

The thing is, some of the distributions I've been using end up being "deterministic", i.e. they have a 1.0 probability of being 1 and 0.0 probability of being 0.

I have been using scipy's stat and the function chisquare to implement my tests. Whenever I try to use the function with those deterministic distributions, the resulting p-value ends up being nan and the test fails even when both distributions being compared are identical.

I do understand that this kind of test should be done in a discretized version of continuous data. So what I'm asking is if there is any workaround to use a chi-square test on a discrete and maybe even "deterministic" distribution.

An MVCE:

```
#!/usr/bin/env
from scipy import stats

distA = [1.0, 0.0]
distB = [1.0, 0.0]
X, p = stats.chisquare(distA, distB)
print X
print p
```

Both X and p should have a value of nan.

Comment: You could use custom exceptions and exception handling to take care of strange cases like that.  There's not enough code in the question to provide an example.  When there is only one possible category, the degrees of freedom will be zero, and that is probably what is blowing up the numerical statistics.

Comment: Please provide a MVCE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I get `nan`s with a call such as `chisquare([10, 0], [10, 0])`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser an MVCE was added, as required. The sum of a distribution has to be 1, so using an array  such as [10, 0] would never work. The array has to sum to 1.

Comment: @franchzilla: Actually, the sum of the arguments to `chisquare` do not have to be 1.  They can be interpreted as observed and expected counts of events rather than fractions.  But that distinction is not relevant to your issue, which is the occurrence of 0 in the same slot of both arguments.